# fastboot flash bootloader = FAILED (remote: (InvalidState))

Tags: adb, nexus-7, fastboot

I'm trying to flash bootloader on my Nexus 7 (2012) and getting `FAILED`:

```
mbp:nakasi-lrx21p alexus$ fastboot flash bootloader bootloader-grouper-4.23.img
sending 'bootloader' (2100 KB)...
OKAY [  0.305s]
writing 'bootloader'...
FAILED (remote: (InvalidState))
finished. total time: 0.445s
mbp:nakasi-lrx21p alexus$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: or maybe it's due to I already have `bootloader-grouper-4.23.img` installed?

Answer (score 4):

According to this [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2417097) it's an issue with the bootloader file. You could try downloading a different factory image for your device and try the bootloader from there instead (the recent images have all had the same 4.23 version, although different files).

> Does anyone else get a "invalidState" and "signature mismatch" message
>   when trying to flash the bootloader.img from the new JWR66Y factory
>   image? Flashing the previous bootloader.img from JWR66V image or JDQ39
>   image works just fine though.

Although the thread refers to a JellyBean issue I encountered the same problem when flashing my Nexus 7 to the Lollipop (LRX21P) factory image as well. As I already had v4.23 I did not flash a new bootloader, my Nexus 7 has booted ok so you could skip it all together.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out for me, I'm using `Nexus 7` (2012) aka first generation.

Comment: Thanks. Yes good is to just skip this step :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Issue 62198 - android - FAILED (remote: (InvalidState)) - Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker - Google Project Hosting](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62198&)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. I fixed it by updating `fastboot` and `adb` from the latest SDK. I had older versions installed from the Ubuntu repos. Note: I still got that error message, but the flash proceeded rather than halting.